# What is the most efficient way to count the results of a stored procedure, from another stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a stored procedure, I need to get the count of the results of another stored procedure. Specifically, I need to know if it returns any results, or an empty set.

I could create a temp table/table variable, exec the stored procedure into it, and then run a select count on that data.  But I really don't care about the data itself, all I need is the count (or presence/absence of data). I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of getting just that information.

I don't want to just copy the contents of the other stored procedure and rewrite it as a select count. The stored procedure changes too frequently for that to be workable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on how the stored procedures work, @@ROWCOUNT returns the # of results for ANYthing that SP will do (including updates):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

This will only work if the LAST thing you do in the sp is returning the rows to the client... Otherwise you're going to get the results of some other statement. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

@@ROWCOUNT

Answer (score 1):

use an out parameter

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could return the number of rows (using RETURN) or use an out parameter to get the value.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's a good idea. Because the return value has int type and you can not pass a bigint with it. So in case you have a table with millions of records with a bigint primary key, your solution might be at risk and it just doesn't work. In addition I should say that the definition of return value in sql is to just report the result of a operation and nothing else (like enumerations in C# it should always have some specific values). Probably it is better using the output parameters to do such a thing or as our friend already said, use @@RowCount variable. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you can rewrite other procedure to be a simple function that returns a resultset, you can simply select count(*) from it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is someone else altering the other stored procedure and you need something to effectively check on the results no matter the changes to such procedure.

Create a tempt table and insert the result from that procedure in it.

Then you can perform a row count on the results. It is not the most efficient but most reliable solution if I understand correctly your problem.

Snipet:

```
DECLARE @res AS TABLE (
    [EmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MgrID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT @res 
EXEC dbo.ProcFoo

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @res
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't really need to know the count, merely whether there is or isn't data  for your sproc, I'd recommend something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE subProcedure @param1, @param2, @Param3 tinyint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE we have something to work with)
   BEGIN
    -- The body of your sproc
    SET @Param3 = 1
   END
  ELSE
   SET @Param3 = 0
END
```

Now you can execute the sproc and check the value of @Param3:

```
DECLARE @ThereWasData tinyint
exec subProcedure 'foo', 'bar', @ThereWasData OUTPUT
IF @ThereWasData = 1 
  PRINT 'subProcedure had data'
ELSE
  PRINT 'subProcedure had NO data'
```

Comment: -1 Because the "TinyInt" data type is not a good choice for count of records in a database, especially when you are working on some large data. It is very clear that you don't know how big the database would be in the future as while as your software is working on and on until then. A complete solution should work always, not exceptional. So I think you should change the datatype. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
Create  Procedure   [dbo].[GetResult]   (
    @RowCount   BigInt  =   -1  Output
)   As  Begin

    /*
        You can do whatever else you should do here.
    */

    Select  @RowCount   =   Count_Big(*)
        From    dbo.SomeLargeOrSmallTable
        Where   SomeColumn  =   'Somefilters'
        ;

    /*
        You can do whatever else you should do here.
    */

    --Reporting how your procedure has done the statements. It's just a sample to show you how to work with the procedures. There are many ways for doing these things.
    Return  @@Error;

End;
```

After writing that you can get the output result like this:

```
Declare @RowCount   BigInt
,   @Result     Int
;

Execute @Result =   [dbo].[GetResult]   @RowCount   Out

Select  @RowCount
,   @Result
;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
  create proc test
    as
    begin
     select top 10 * from customers
    end
    go


    create proc test2 (@n int out)
    as
    begin
    exec test
    set @n = @@rowcount
    --print @n
    end
    go

    declare @n1 int =0

    exec test2 @n1 out
    print @n1
    --output result: 10
```